# A text file list for each archive with relative name

Tags: powershell, batch, script, winrar

To get a list of files inside a .rar archive I can use this batch

```
@(for /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test winrar" %%I in (*.rar) do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" lb "%%I")>files.txt
```

But I want another thing: create a text list file for each .rar archive and not just a single-one text file list for all archives. No, for each archive, one file

I have many archives, with my batch I create a single text file, but I want create a text file list for each archive with relative name.

```
name1.rar => name1.txt
name2.rar => name2.txt
name3.rar => name3.txt
...
```

Instead, my script, create just a single file list and this is not useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimum edit you can get this results:

```bat
@(for /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test winrar" %%I in (*.rar)do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" lb "%%I">"%%~nI.txt" & type "%%~nI.txt">>Files.txt)

rem :: or....

@(for /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test winrar" %%I in (*.rar)do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" lb "%%~I">"%%~nI.txt" & type "%%~nI.txt")>Files.txt
```

> Your script works, thank you. Just a last thing wired: if I would to generate a >file list only for a particular archive, for example only for archive called "11eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar" and I want to use a batch, how can I change >your script? – Jack 41

---

- If you need only `"11eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"` contend listed in `Files.txt`:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" 

set "_path=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test"
set "_wRar="%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe""
set "_File=11eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"

for /f eol^=^|^tokens^=*delims^=^  %%i in ('
%__AppDir__%where.exe /R "%_path%" "%_File%"
    ')do %_WRar% lb "%%~i" >"%~dp0%%~ni.txt"
```

- If you need to exclude `"11eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"` contend from `Files.txt`:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_File=1eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"
set "_path=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test winrar"
set "_wRar="%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe""

>.\Files.txt (for /R "%_path%" %%I in (*.rar
)do if /i "%_File%"=="%%~nxI" > "%%~nI.txt"(
  %_WRar% lb "%%~I") else %_WRar% lb "%%~I")
```

- If you need a separate list of the file `"11eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"` but not included in `Files.txt`:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_File=1eyes Music Collection (FLAC).rar"
set "_path=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test winrar"
set "_wRar="%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe""

     >.\Files.txt (for /R "%_path%" %%I in (
       *.rar) do if /i "%_File%"=="%%~nxI" (
         %_WRar% lb "%%~I" >"%%~nI.txt" && (
           %_WRar% lb "%%~I")) else ^< nul ^
             %_WRar% lb "%%~I") && goto :eof
```

- If you want to get a file listing by *dragging and dropping* or *`argument`*:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

<con: "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" lb "%~dpnx1" >"%~dp0%~n1.txt"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[Where /?](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

**[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**

Comment: @Jack  A need new glasses!  Thank you for yours comments, plz, the check last edit...

Comment: Thank you, now it works, it was just an inversion

Comment: @Jack Thank you too!